# Connect many Buttons to the same function in a for loop

Tags: python, pyqt

I have about 25-30 Buttons which I must to connect to the same function. I don't like to do this all manually by writing

```
self.__mybutton_1.clicked.connect(self.__MyConnectedFunction)
```

All my buttons have the same naming layout, so the next button would be `__mybutton_2`. I want to do something like that

```
for i in range(10):
    self.__mybutton_i.clicked.connect(self.__MyConnectedFunction)
```

Is something like this possible in python and how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but not recommended.  You *can* use `eval("self.__mybutton_{}".format(i)).connect(self.__MyConnectedFunction)`, but it would be better to create a list of your buttons and use `buttons[i]` instead.

Comment: I know that a list will be the better option. I am new in QT and using Wx until now and I'm very happy with the QT Designer. There I have lot of buttons, not in a list...

Comment: Well, if you really *can't* use a list, the `eval()` function should work.

Answer (score 0):

If all the buttons are children of the same widget/window, you could use the [`QObject.findChildren`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#findChildren-3) method to dynamically get a list of the buttons:

```
btns = self.findChildren(QtGui.QPushButton, QtCore.QRegExp(r'__mybutton_\d+'))
for btn in btns:
    btn.connect(self._MyConnectedFunction)
```

This also assumes you're setting the `objectName` of the buttons to the same name as their python variable name (which `.ui` files should already do).

This has the benefit that you can add more buttons in the future and as long as you stick to the naming convention (`__my_button_#`), the connection code will automatically connect it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do exactly what you want using [getattr](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
for i in range(10):
    button = getattr(self, '__mybutton_%s' % i)
    button.clicked.connect(self.__MyConnectedFunction)
```